# Objects in HashMap - pass to ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, listadapter

Is it possible to pass both strings and drawables as objects in the same HashMap, and then use this hashmap to populate a ListView via SimpleAdapter ?

I want this because I first get JSON data which also contains the URL to a thumbnail. Then I download this thumbnail. Relevant code (I think):

```
for (...) {
    ...
    InputStream is = (InputStream)content;

    Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");

    // Hashmap          
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    map.put("title", new String(jsonObject.getString("Title")));
    map.put("thumb", image);

    mylist.add(map);
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, R.layout.listitem,
        new String[] { "title", "thumb"},
        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.thumb });

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

R.id.title = TextView, and R.id.thumb = ImageView

This works for the title string, but not for the drawable. Is this approach just stupid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a XML layout file for your row representation in the list and a custom adapter that inflate your row

Comment: This being a `SimpleAdapter`, I would rather try to supply a `ViewBinder` before going all the way down to implement my own custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from [the `SimpleAdapter` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html), `ImageView`s are supported only for binding with a resource identifier or a `String`, which (the `String`, I mean) [must represent an image resource or an image URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewImage%28android.widget.ImageView,%20java.lang.String%29). It won't work if you pass it directly a `Drawable` object.